# Can EntityObject be used to directly generate a view for various scaffolds?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

When I add a strongly typed view I see my Entities listed in the Model class dropdown.  But, if I select an entity and Scaffold, say List, I get a runtime error of **object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

In past projects I created a Service layer that called LINQ using CRUD.  Then I consumed this service in my Controller and manually created the Views from the resulting service classes.  It would be a lot easier if MVC just did all that for me.

Is it possible to directly create scaffold views from concrete classes inheriting `EntityObject`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer : Yes.

I just tried the following test case...

New Project

Create EDMX

Build

Add Controller (With Read/Write actions and views using entity framework

pick Model class and context (the thing normally suffixed with 'entities'

click add

run - it works

EDIT: added MVC Scaffolding too...

open package manager

Install-Package MvcScaffolding

Add Controller (MVC Scaffolding controller With read/write actions  & views using EF COde)

Build and Run : Also works.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by using package manager to install MvcScaffolding.  Does something need to be installed outside of the basic MVC 3 package?  Considering I already have the option to scaffold and see my Entities listed shouldn't this already be installed?  My test case is similar to yours, but it does not work.  Any idea why I would get an object reference error?  I tried both the context object and an entity representing a table.

Comment: I think I know what I did wrong to get the object reference error.  I did not generate a controller using the process above.  When I try to generate a controller I get an error.  With the context object I get "Edm.EntityType: AventureworksDWEntities' One or more validation errors detected" and it says no key defined for 'AdventureworksDWEntities'.

Comment: When I try the table entity I get "unable to retrieve metadata for DatabaseDocumentor.Models.DatabaseLog". the type was not mapped.

Comment: you will have to describe the process you are using in detail for me to help more. Meanwhile - package-manager is the NuGet Library Package Manager. There is some scafolding in the MVC3 tools update - more in the Scaffolding nuget package. For details see http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/ and for info on NuGet try http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingNuPackPackageManagementForNETAnotherPieceOfTheWebStack.aspx